# Entity Framework, Computed Entity Field

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

Is it possible to include a computed field in an EF entity? Example, lets say I have a shop selling products, and the products are grouped into categories.

When the list of categories is displayed for editing to the administrator of the shop I wish to list the number of products in each category as part of the list.

In NHibernate I would use a formula e.g.

```
<property name="Products" formula="dbo.Category_NumProducts(id)" />
```

I can't work out if something similar is possible for EF. I know I could make a category view and map this to a second entity but that seems wrong as its almost a complete duplication.

EDIT: If this isn't possible in EF, then what is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately if your `Category` table doesn't have this as computed column you will not be able to map it without creating second entity - it leads to database view, defining query in EDMX or perhaps Query view in EDMX (but Query view may not work because you require aggregate function to be computed).

Edit:

IMHO the simplest solution (and also the best) is simply creating a ViewModel (some non mapped class) and use projection in Linq query:

```
var query = from c in context.Categories
            where ...
            select new CategoryView {
                Id = c.Id,
                Name = c.Name,
                ...
                Products = c.Products.Count()
            };
```

Comment: OK thanks, that is the impression I'd got. And are the approaches you've mentioned (view, defining query etc), the correct ways to solve such a problem? I'm just checking that I'm not approaching it from the wrong angle. Cheers

Comment: OK, that makes sense, as I'm using the repository pattern I'd probably need to create an second entity as you originally suggested. Hmmm its making me like NHibernate more and more, and I never liked it in the first place :)

Comment: NHibernate is more mature and it has a lot of advanced features which seem to complicating its usage until you find those features necessary. Even with repository pattern you can still use simple projection as showed in my answer.

Comment: OK, so I've built a repository that doesn't expose IQueryable, therefore if I carried out a projection as above I'm assuming that it would pull all the actual product records in? Which would be a bit of a performance hit?

Comment: You can have specialized method on your repository encapsulating the projection.